# how can i Find companies near me

Tags: xcode, navigation, gps, find

I have been searching a long time that codes. i want to create my app and when user open it, program find it gps location from google maps and will show companies near him. and show the "how to go there" as like google maps.
there are a lots of apps like that. but i cannot find the source codes. do you have any idea or example codes for kind of this app?
Thanks and Best Regards.
Fatih

Comment: Sort of like the app called "Around Me"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests). One of the parameters passed to the API server is the location in latitude and longitude coordinates. The result data can be returned in either JSON or XML format.

Comment: I've used google place api , and there is a parameter "types=company".
But ,it is not showing any values within 20 km . But , my company is 14km from my home from google map.